# BreezeJS: Applying Client Query in Controller

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

Is there anyway to apply the user query in the controller in order to perform some actions to the final result set?

Take the following example:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Container> Containers(bool populate)
{
    var containers = _contextProvider.Context.Containers;
    if (populate)
    {
         foreach (var container in containers)
         {
             container.Populate(_contextProvider.Context);
         }
    }
    return containers;
}
```

The problem here is that I am doing this `Populate()` action to all records in this table instead of just the ones that the user requested because their query has not been applied yet. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the ODataQueryOptions passed into your method, so you can apply them manually instead of letting WebApi apply them on the way out.

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Container> Containers(ODataQueryOptions options, bool populate)
{
    IQueryable<Container> containers = _contextProvider.Context.Containers;
    containers = options.ApplyTo(Containers).Cast<Container>();
    if (populate)
    {
        foreach (var container in containers)
        {
            container.Populate(_contextProvider.Context);
        }
    }
    return containers;
}
```